# Usar startActivity dentro de un View en Kotlin Android

Tags: android, activity, kotlin

Para abrir una `activity` desde otra actividad uso

```
startActivity(Intent(this, SegundaActivity::class.java)
```

Pero no ser como hacer referencia al `this` cuando lo quiero lanzar al pulsar un botón...
en java lo indico con `MainActivity.this` pero en Kotlin no ser como se puede hacer referencia a la actividad madre.

```
fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
    startActivity(Intent(???this???, SegundaActivity::class.java)
}
```

Comment: Con `this` no te deja?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
startActivity(Intent(this@CurrentClassName,RequiredClassName::class.java)
```

En tu código se vería algo así:

```
fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
    startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity,ClassName::class.java))
}
```

Comment: Utilizando solamente `this` tambien es valido.